# How to remove an event listener that is a closure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have an event handler that is a closure

```
halt = (socket, room) ->
  (sid) ->
    if sid is socket.id
      socket.broadcast.to(room).emit 'halt'
```

I attach this listener to a global emitter each time a socket connects. When the socket disconnects, I want to remove the listener.

```
@io.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  haltFn = halt socket, 'kitchen'
  emitter.on 'halt',  haltFn

  socket.on 'disconnect', ->
    emitter.removeListener 'halt', haltFn
```

From the logs, I can see the function inside of `halt` is being called for as many times as connections have occurred even after some disconnections. How can I properly remove the listener?

Comment: What do you mean by "even after *some* disconnections"? Isn't that what it's supposed to do, remove only the `haltFn` of its own connection and let the rest stay?

Comment: Example flow: user1 connects, user2 connects, user1 disconnects, user1 connects, halt event is emitted, `haltFn` is run 3 times

Comment: Hm, that *is* odd. What 3 sockets is the `halt` event emitted to, have you logged them? Are they really the closed sockets of user1 and user2?